Nodemailer contact us form
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
service: "gmail",
auth: {
    user: "example@gmail.com",
    pass: "password",
},

});
app.post("/api/send", (req, res) => {
const { email, mobile, message } = req.body;
const mailOptions = {
    from: email, //this email is received from the contact us form 
    to: "receiverEmail@gmail.com",
    subject: "Message from this App",
    text: message
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);
    }
    res.status(200).json({message:"Message sent sucessfully"});
});

});
I want the this piece of code to send mail to the specified to filed in the mail options from "receiver@gmail.com" from the sender email which is received from the request not from the node mailer auth user which is example@gmail.com. I am getting the message from example@gmail.com not from the email which is entered by someone who fill up the contact up form.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Ah yes, I know this problem. Using Gmail as your SMTP relay does have this limitation, and it is clearly described in Nodemailer's documentation as:

Gmail also always sets authenticated username as the From: email address. So if you authenticate as foo@example.com and set bar@example.com as the from: address, then Gmail reverts this and replaces the sender with the authenticated user.

A minor work around is to include the senders email, name etc. in the body of the email that gets sent to you. That way, you still get that info.
If your contact form is used for a company/organisation, a better workaround is to use a cheap service, and I think the cheapest right now would be one of the cloud providers, especially AWS SES. Otherwise just keep using the free options out there.
